# Node server not working on live

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, redis, laravel-5.1

I have an app that can pass notification using node.js and redis on Laravel framework. It works good on local but when I deploy it on staging server it is not working. Please help me.
We are using [Forge.Laravel.com](http://forge.laravel.com/) on our live server.

This is my **server.js** on root_folder/nodejs/server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

// Check if server is listening on its port 
server.listen(8890, 'my_ip_address_on_live', function() {
  console.log('Listening on your port');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("new client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();

  redisClient.subscribe('notification-channel', function(err, count) {
  });

redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message) {
    console.log( " message= "+ message + " channel = " + channel);
    socket.emit(channel, message);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

This is my **package.json**

```
"express": "^4.13.4",
"ioredis": "^2.0.1",
"redis": "^2.6.1",
"socket.io": "^1.4.6"
```

On staging in will log only:

> Listening on your port

And I think the problem is the socket cant connect because it does not log
"new client connected".
This is my first time using nodejs. Thanks

Comment: Where is your staging server hosted? Does your host permit traffic to port 8890?

Comment: @ceejayoz We are using http://forge.laravel.com/ ... How to know sir that the host permit traffic on port 8890? Sorry im a newbie

Comment: Forge support multiple hosts (AWS, DigitalOcean, Linode, etc.), so that's hard to answer. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/how-to-expose-port-on-laravel-forge-on-do-with-ubuntu-1404-server indicates you might be able to do it within Forge's admin UI, but I don't personally use it.

Comment: @ceejayoz ok sir I will this instantly. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes you're right sir! I need only to add the port on the admin pane. Why I didnt think of that. :( Thank you so much sir God Bless You

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy!